# Find sum of the largest X numbers in arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

Given an array of number from 1 to 100, find the sum of the greatest x numbers.  Please let me know if you have any solution to this question in java

Comment: Sort in reverse order. Get sum of first `X` elements.

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a place where your job done for you. Please consider showing some research effort (posting some code).

Comment: @RohitJain But please use a linear-time sort

Comment: @NiklasB. Linear time sort -> I'm seeing that for the first time. That would never be possible.

Comment: @RohitJain That's just plain untrue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort For numbers in a constant range, it's very possible

Comment: I am trying to use arithmetic progression for this.

Comment: sum=1/2(first number+last Number)* N

Comment: I removed the [java] tag, because the question is language-agnostic

Comment: @NiklasB. I heard of that sort, used in once in college. But didn't know it is linear time. :)

Comment: @RohitJain When you say it's "impossible", you probably think of the comparison-based sort lower bound of *Ω(n log n)* comparisons. But in many cases you have more information than just *0/1* comparisons. Radix sort is *O(wn)*, for example, where *w* is the bitsize of the numbers, so it would also be linear time for integer arrays with a bounded range

Comment: If there aren't any other issues to consider here, this is easily done by just ordering the array and picking the first/last X numbers (depending on sort order). If there *are* issues to consider here, they must be described.

Comment: @Lasse If I read algorithm or interview questions, I always assume an implicit optimality condition (asymptotically most efficient way to do X)

Comment: I always assume that if people wanted me to take something into account they would've told me about it, but then I'm funny that way. (like the fact that this is an interview question). In the context of being an interview question, I would probably have to go with a heap data structure. Then again, 100 numbers? really? Even with O(n^2) it's going to be peanuts to modern CPUs.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen *n* is the length of the array, which could be arbitrarily large. Not sure what you mean, but yeah, linear time is definitely possible here

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen You're having the same issue as I had. Its not an array of 100 numbers. Its an array of numbers whose value is 1 to 100. The counting sort is contingent upon knowing the max number in the array, which is < 100. I'm not sure how it would do if the max were 10^100.

Comment: @deanosaur Then it would still be linear time ;) It just has to be bounded. But it would probably start to be better than the sorting-based solutions only when your array has more than 10^100 elements, which is not a very likely scenario in practice

Comment: @Niklas B. That makes sense. Thanks. I never saw this one before.

Comment: Without knowing much more about the problem I would use a heap data structure, and just prune it to always keep X numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) for linear runtime:

```
count = [0,...,0]  
for item in array:
    count[item]++

sum = 0
i = 100
while x > 0:
    take = min(x, count[i])
    x -= take
    sum += i * take
    i--
```

Comment: Can't make an edit this short, but there is a slight typo.  You have count[x]++ you want count[item]++

Comment: Help me understand how `for item in array: count[item]++` works?

Comment: @deanosaur Go through the array, increment count[item] for every `item` in the array. What is unclear about that? Or do you mean what the intention of that is? Essentially this is just counting sort only that we don't need to reconstruct the full sorted array

Comment: I get it, thanks. You need allocate an array of max(item) size `count[0,...,0]`. Is there way to generalize this algorithm when max(item) is unknown?

Comment: @deanosaur You can find `M = max(array)` in O(n). You will need *O(M + n)* time and *O(min(M, n))* space (using a hash table), so if *M = O(n)*, it's linear time

Comment: @deanosaur Given this example this won't make sense, but if you were to get a very large stream of integers coming in instead of an array you could also do Integer.MAX values.  That only makes sense though if you are getting tons of integers though (so like I said not this example).

Answer (score 1):

Only because the question asked for it in java though Niklas did it in psuedo code

```
public static int greatestSum(int[] array, int x) {
   int[] sorted = new int[100];
   for (int item: array)
      sorted[item - 1]++;

   int sum = 0;
   int index = 99;
   //Check index to prevent out of bounds if array.length < x
   while (x > 0  && index >= 0) {
      int totalAvailable = Math.min(sorted[index], x);
      x = x - totalAvailable;
      sum += ((index + 1) * totalAvailable);
      index--;
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Well its >= but the problem stated that it will be 1 - 100.  I guess I could do a safety check with an IllegalArgumentException if it is outside the bounds of the question.

Comment: I didn't mean to pick nits. I was thinking an array of 100 ints, not array of ints < 100.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple logic.Steps you can follow as below.

Steps :-

1. First you need to sort the given array in reverse order (Desc).
2. Then pass the Nth highest number you want to add.
3. Then Read the sorted array data starting from `[0]` index to `[Nth]` index position.
4. Apply sum method using the counter variable inside the loop ,when you are reading the array elements.

Hope it will help you.